# When using coroutine channels, how do I activate the -> operator?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In this example, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html#prime-numbers-with-pipeline

We are given two functions:

```
fun CoroutineScope.numbersFrom(start: Int) = produce<Int> {
    var x = start
    while (true) send(x++) // infinite stream of integers from start
}
```

```
fun CoroutineScope.filter(numbers: ReceiveChannel<Int>, prime: Int) = produce<Int> {
    for (x in numbers) if (x % prime != 0) send(x)
}
```

However, the example doesn't compile

```
numbersFrom(2) -> filter(2) -> filter(3) -> filter(5) -> filter(7)
```

The compilation error I get is `Expecting comma or ')'`

Is there an import I'm forgetting to use. The imports I have so far are

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ReceiveChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.produce
```

Comment: That line is not a kotlin code, it is just a "view" of what will happen in the channel (the filter function will be launched in chain each time a value arrive in the channel).The actual code exemple is the block below it (`var cur = numbersFrom(2)\n repeat(10) ...`)

Comment: Oh, I understand. Would have been cool to be able to do that. It's available in Scala for example